# Getting [object Object] when receiving and displaying data from omdbapi

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest

My code is doing what I want EXCEPT for this [object Object] that is displaying when I perform a search. I'm probably overlooking something but I cannot find where this is coming from. Thought I would get some fresh eyes on it and see if anyone can see what I'm missing.

JavaScript

```
$('.search-form').submit(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?';
var movie = $('#search').val();
var data = {
    s: movie
};
function callBack(data) {
    var movieHTML = $("#movies").empty();
        $.each(data.Search, function(i, movie) {
            movieHTML += '<li>';
            movieHTML += '<div class="poster-wrap"><img class="movie-poster" src="'+ movie.Poster +'"></div>';
            movieHTML += '<span class="movie-title">'+ movie.Title +'</span>';
            movieHTML += '<span class="movie-year">'+ movie.Year +'</span>';
            movieHTML += '</li>';
            });
        $('#movies').html(movieHTML);
}
$.getJSON(url, data, callBack);
```

and here is an image of what Im getting.

[image: problem screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a data issue to me - use Firebug or the network tab of a developer toolset to check the data coming back from the server, or just use the browser itself to show you the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a specific reason you need to use `var movieHTML = $("#movies").empty();` , but replacing that with `var movieHTML = ''` fixed the issue for me..
**working codepen:**
http://codepen.io/ethanrose/pen/OWVdgP?editors=0010

The jQuery .empty function still returns the dom object, just without any children. so your `var movieHTML` is actually being declared with an `[object, object]` which is that dom object "movies"
**Docs on jQuery .empty**
https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue. I'm pretty new to all of this stuff!